# Find node via xpath in SimpleXML

Tags: php

Trying to find a specific node within a XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<disqus xmlns="http://disqus.com" xmlns:dsq="http://disqus.com/disqus-internals"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://disqus.com/api/schemas/1.0/disqus.xsd http://disqus.com/api/schemas/1.0/disqus-internals.xsd">
    <post dsq:id="2248389859">
        <id/>
        <message><![CDATA[<p>Message</p>]]></message>
        <createdAt>2015-09-11T17:08:10Z</createdAt>
        <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
        <isSpam>false</isSpam>
        <author>
            <name>author</name>
            <isAnonymous>false</isAnonymous>
            <username>author</username>
        </author>
        <thread dsq:id="3828540236"/>
        <parent dsq:id="2246284031"/>
    </post>
</disqus>
```

I'd like to find the `post` via the SimpleXML#xpath method, more specifically via the `thread dsq:id` attribute. But I can't even find the thread itself with

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml")
var_dump($xml->xpath('/disqus');
```

This prints an empty array - but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am rusty with the right terminology, but I think your query is not working because your element is declaring default namespace. It seems to work if you register it with explicit name and use it to query:.

```php
$xml->registerXPathNamespace( 'disqus', 'http://disqus.com' );

$disqus = $xml->xpath( '/disqus:disqus' );
$post   = $xml->xpath( '//disqus:post[disqus:thread/@dsq:id=3828540236]' );
```